# PHP regex last occurrence of words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

My string is: `/var/www/domain.com/public_html/foo/bar/folder/another/..`

I want to remove the root folder from this string, to get only public folder, because some servers have multiple websites inside.

My actual regex is: `/^(.*?)(www|public_html|public|html)/s`

My actual result is: `/domain.com/public_html/foo/bar/folder/another/..`

But i want to remove the last ocorrence, and get somethig like this: `/foo/bar/folder/another/..`

Thanks!

Comment: How I did not realize that? 
thank you so much! @chris85

Comment: You may keep the pattern as is, and just add `U` modifier. And remove the `s` if there can be no line breaks in your input string.

Comment: Can you not use `explode`?

Comment: regex is much better @Script47

Comment: @Leonardo how so? Any source? Genuinely interested as I'm not in to regex so it might be an incentive for the future to make use of it instead.

Comment: The problem you appear to describe is finding the base path of your application - but you have set a context which is misleading - if you are trying to determine the base path, then the solution you have accepted is wrong.

Comment: I have no source, it's just a matter of taste @Script47

Comment: Are you an idea for a better solution for me to suggest? @symcbean

Comment: Have a look at DOCUMENT_ROOT and REQUEST_URI in $_SERVER

Comment: Im usin this script without headers, im executing ssh line command @symcbean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a greedy quantifier and to check if the alternative is enclosed between slashes using lookarounds:

```
/^.*(?<![^\/])(?:www|public(?:_html)?|html)(?![^\/])/
```

About the lookarounds: I use negative lookarounds with a negated character class to check if there is a slash or the limit of the string at the same time. This way you are sure that for instance `html` is a folder and not the part of another folder name.

I removed the s modifier that is useless. I removed the capture groups too since the goal is to replace all with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` makes your expression non-greedy which is not actually what you want here. Try:

```
^(.*)(www|public_html|public|html)
```

which should keep going until the last match.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/v5WbB3/1/